# How to get UCSC Genome Browser to show the actual sequence?

Tags: genome-browser

Is it possible to make UCSC Genome Browser to show the sequence (nucleotide chain) of the current region?

I fiddled with the various viewing options and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you zoom in at one specific region, it shows the nucleotide chain on the third line (below the chromosome number). It can't be there by default as the size of default region is more than 100,000bp. You can use the scale on the top of the page to see the size of the region.

[image: UCSC Genome Browser Example]

Answer (score 0):

In case it’s of any benefit to you, I’ll often check [IGV](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/) when looking at tracks with that kind of zoomage. Not that it zooms any better than the UCSC browser (although the bases are colour coded!) but you can see your aligned reads individually if you want, along with directional information etc etc. Loads of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

From the top bar:
View -> DNA

[image]